Movie about man surviving in desert after his attempted murder by his wife and her lover
I remember watching this movie on TV over 10 years ago. It starts with the story of a couple where the wife is cheating on her husband in their house. The husband finds out but is confronted and intimidated by his wife's boyfriend.
In a later scene, the wife and her boyfriend attempt to kill the husband by pushing him off a cliff in a desert area. Unbeknownst to them, he was able to survive and live off hunting and gathering.
After finding out, they return to the desert to finish the job, but this time, the husband is ready for them and keeps evading them and stealthily fighting back.

 He ends up causing the death of both of them. I don't remember how the boyfriend died, but the wife was killed when a rifle backfired as she was trying to shoot the husband


Sounds like Sand Trap from 1998.

After falling victim to a burglar, Nelson, a wealthy businessman, takes a trip to the desert with his wife Margo and lawyer/friend Jack. The trip takes an unexpected turn when Jack helps Nelson over a cliff. Jack and Margo return to the site with the sheriff only to discover Nelson's body is missing, indicating he is still alive. As Nelson struggles to survive against madness and the elements, two separate searches for him are conducted--one by an increasingly suspicious sheriff and the other by the treacherous Margo and Jack.

Nelson survives the desert and finally confronts his wife, who dies when her gun backfires. It's worth noting there's a similar film called Inferno from 1953 (remade as Ordeal in 1973). Here's the trailer.




That's definitely a match. Thank you
